# Best way for Data storage

Tags: android

I have a Tabel with Buttons, 9 rows and 5 columns -> 45 Buttons. Each Button sould have the properties:
row, week, time, day, name, description, colour, room.
What is the best way for the storage? Do I have to use the complicated SQLite, or is there a easier solution? I'm new in Android, therefore SQLite is not easy for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would take some time to implement a ContentProvider and use a SQLite db...
However, you can use a lot of different approaches, you can save all your information in a private file (so you can format them as you wish) or use the SharedPreferences mechanism.

You should have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to read about the different methods

Comment: Thanks, I will take a lokk to the SQLite db.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it is static set of 45 buttons and does not require permanent persistence. There are two days you can solve it

- Extend Button class and define the properties you need
- Use [setTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29) to store carry in-memory data objects along with view objects. So in your case create a [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) object for each button and store it in the button view with setTag.